# Can't publish apps to Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, playback

I was uploading my apps to the Play Store. My apps, which I set the age limit to be 5 years old, haven't been published for 2 weeks? why?

Yes, I forgot about this. Some apps were rejected once, but some were not rejected the first time. Issue: Inaccurate Target Audience
We determined that your app and store listing contain elements that appeal primarily to children, therefore the target age groups you've selected are inaccurate. For example, your store listing contains elements such as:
Animated characters in the app icon.
Young characters.
Multiple references to keywords related to children.
If your primary target audience is children, you must select the appropriate age groups in the Target Audience and Content section and comply with all Designed for Families Requirements. it was like that

Comment: can you specify the details that playstore status is been shown whether its rejected or under reiview

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about this, I edited the problem, thanks

Comment: All apps have been moved to the family apps section.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Privacy Policy must need to add for <13 year children.
Must sure that your store listing is above 13 age group.
I suggest that make sure you provide privacy policy of your app.

Comment: Privacy policy https://app.freeprivacypolicy.com/wizard/privacy-policy created through this site Does not apply to create through this site <13

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).